# Bypassing the reCAPTCHA and login using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a web-crawling project and want to scrape some news articles from the website *https://www.utusan.com.my/*

While logging in the website there is a reCAPTCHA which I wanna bypass, even if clicked the CAPTCHA using selenium it taking me to the picture test to confirm identity. I was wondering if there is any way to bypass that and login. I even tried with Chrome Undetected Driver but didn't worked out. Please help me with this.

Here is my code with which I tried,

```
   import undetected_chromedriver as uc 
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    lists = ['disable-popup-blocking']

    caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
    caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"

    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument("--disable-Advertisement")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
    
    username = <username>
    password = <password>

    driver.get('https://www.utusan.com.my/akaun/')
    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys(username)
    # input user name
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys(password)  
    # input password
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit').click()
```

Comment: I don't recommend you bypassing a captcha that was created to handle bots. What you are creating now is a bot. Instead, I recommend contacting the web master if you really need their data and ask for alternatives to scrape them. They may provide you an api or some sort to scrape them safely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://get.brightdata.com/lp-scraping-browser-acf1036?sid=c001) might help. It uses the Chrome Devtools Protocol to connect (via Websocket) to a remote Chrome instance running on their servers, which handles proxies, CAPTCHA solving etc. automatically for you with no extra app code. I've only used it with Playwright but I know it can be easily integrated within your existing Selenium script too (you can find the instructions [here](https://get.brightdata.com/getting-started-with-scraping-browser?sid=c001)).